# What is Monero's release naming convention?

Tags: release-naming

The last two Monero releases are alliteratively named Hydrogen Helix and Wolfram Warptangent. Is there a convention used to name those releases, such as Ubuntu's also alliterative adjective/animal archetype (see what I did there) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Monero's naming convention of a chemical element + a star or constellation is the result of a discussion on the official forum: "[Now for some fun: naming Monero releases](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2352/now-for-some-fun-naming-monero-releases)"

Regarding alliteration:

> "using alliteration / assonance for maximum awesomeness." (fluffypony)

First release with this scheme is 0.9.0 ("Hydrogen Helix") and has been chosen in thread [Name the Next Monero Release!](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2394/name-the-next-monero-release)

For v0.10.0 ("Wolfram Warptangent"), the scheme has been partially ignored to honor contributor [Warptangent](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4c9wh8/a_fond_goodbye_to_our_friend_and_contributor/) who passed away and had done a lot of work on the project among other on RingCT.

Note: Wolfram is an other name for Tungsten.
[image: By Alchemist-hp (talk) (www.pse-mendelejew.de) - Own work, FAL, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=10424635]
(Wikipedia, By Alchemist-hp (talk) (www.pse-mendelejew.de) - Own work, FAL, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=10424635)

Comment: On the other side, if we consider Warptangent as a star of the Monero project, the scheme is respected...